# How do I use rags to stop bleeding?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I have some clean rags that I found in a first aid kit, and I would like to use them as a bandage, but I can't figure out how. Clicking Consume on them does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use bandages, you need to use the Medical screen.  I believe the hotkey is <kbd>C</kbd>.

First, take the clean rag out of wherever you have it stored.  Then switch to the Medical screen, and find where you're bleeding.  You'll be able to drop the rag onto the wound like it's got an inventory slot.

I'm not sure if rags go from clean to dirty (my one character who survived long enough to bandage died shortly thereafter), but if they do, you should be able to remove the dirty rag, and replace it with a clean one.

Comment: The bandages do become dirty rags, although I'm unsure if at that point the wound still requires a bandage or not.

Comment: @TrentHawkins In my experience, wounds heal long before a 100% clean rag decays to "dirty".  I usually leave them on until that point, though, for ease of cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered already, but I wanted to put a bit more clarity on the medical system with bandages. yes, you can access the medical screen with hot key C, or by clicking the button on the side of the screen with the health care symbol, which can be accessed at any time (even under safe conditions during a fight such as when the enemy is unconscious or a certain distance away from the player).

there are two common types of injuries to treat using rags: bruises and cuts. cuts are an open wound, so you should treat those with a clean cloth. Place the cloth onto the wound through dragging from the injury and onto that specific wound. The cloth will degrade overtime as the wound heals. once the rag degrades to zero, it becomes a dirty rag, which is  still useful in medical treatments. the wound should heal more quickly with a rag, either clean or dirty, but the wounds can heal by themselves. I will be testing to see if dirty rags will cause an infection to open wounds.

Bruises, however, are not open wounds, and I have safely applied dirty rags on them without ever receiving an infection. bruises on the torso or head are treatable by clean and dirty rags, but you cannot apply them to limbs.

Bruises can grow into broken bones if attacked repeatedly, which is why you should treat it as a "potential" broken bone and heal it with a splint. also, this was my first answer for a question to this website. is it possible to change what you wrote?

Comment: Yep, you can click the [edit] button at the bottom of your post to make changes